# converting the predicted probabilities to binary outputs and ResourceExhaustedError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have defined the following loss function:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.gather(y_pred, tf.where(y_pred>0.5))
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersect = K.sum(y_pred_f * y_true_f)
    denominator = K.sum(y_pred_f) + K.sum(y_true_f)
    dice_score = K.constant(2.) * intersect / (denominator + K.constant(.01))
    return dice_score
```

Since I only want the y_pred to be 0 and 1s, I followed a thread on stackoverflow that suggested using `y_pred = K.gather(y_pred, tf.where(y_pred>0.5))`. I am however getting the error:

> ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[662885,4,144,144,1]

Any fix around this problem?

Comment: You don't have enough memory. And you can try to reduce `batch_size`.

Comment: Are you using a batch size of 662885 ?

Comment: My batch size is 32

Comment: Try smaller batch. Also I believe you don't have to calculate score this way.
You are developing a regression model, but you need to get classification output. So change your model.
If you use one output as linear function in your output layer to get the prediction value, change it two output with some function like softmax and replace your loss function to categorical_crossentropy.